# Unity 2D Directly modifying rotation.z causes a strange "smooth/lerping" rotation that stops at 180

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing a strange issue with how the Unity transform rotation values are affected. This may just be a Unity thing but I can't find info about why it would act the way that it is. What I'm experiencing is a strange lerping affect of the rotation values when I try to incrementally increase the rotation of my 2D character.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 1f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        Quaternion rot = transform.rotation;

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            pos += transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            rot.z += 2 * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            rot.z -= 2 * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Update the position
        transform.position = pos;
        transform.rotation = rot;

    }
}
```

GIF of the issue

[image]

You can see in the GIF that the rotation value increases quickly at first and then begins to slow down as it approaches the 180 mark. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: if you have a 2D game, i dont understand why you are using axis z? could you explain?

Comment: @Frenchy in 2D mode the `Z` or forward axis is the one you want to rotate around as `X` and `Y` are the ones you move in

Comment: ok thanks for explanation derHugo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rot` is a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) and unless you know exactly what you are doing **never** directly change its components .. which are not only `x`, `y`, `z` but also `w` and all move between `-1` and `1`.

What you see here is probably your value reaching the max value and then being clamped at `z = 1`

---

Rather use e.g. [`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) or [`Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * angle)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) and [`*` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) instead

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        transform.position += transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        // Either directly rotate
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 2 * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        // Or use Eulers
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * -2 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```